# AWS S3 file uploads inside a thread not completing

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

This is the scenario. There is a consumer, which consumes file names from a kafka queue and uploads those files to S3.

Between the consumer and the uploader, there is a thread pool executor which uses blocking queue, of fixed size 10. The consumer consumes the file names and submits the upload task, which implements Runnable, to the thread pool executor.

UploaderTask.java

```
...
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Uploading...");
        Uploader uploader = new Uploader();
        uploader.uploadFile("/home/user/a.txt");
        System.out.println("Uploaded");
    } catch(...) {
        ...
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Clean up task");
    }
}
...
```

Uploader.java

```
public class Uploader {
    void upload(String fileName) {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .build();
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new 
        PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, "key.txt", new File(fileName));
        PutObjectResult putObjectResult = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
        System.out.println("Upload done. Returning");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Uploading...
Clean up task
```

The line after s3.putobject(...) does not seem to be executing and also the code after uploader.uploadFile(...)

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    try {
        System.out.println("Uploading...");
        Uploader uploader = new Uploader();
        uploader.uploadFile("/home/user/a.txt");
        System.out.println("Uploaded");
    } catch(...) {
        ...
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Clean up task");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Uploading...
Upload done. Returning
Uploaded
Clean up task
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's in the `catch`?  Is any error at least logged?

Comment: Looks like an exception was thrown, but it was eaten.

Comment: Also, creating a new AmazonS3 instance for each thread is a waste of resources.  It's thread safe so create a single instance to share among all threads.